# Authentications issue (com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel)

Tags: java, ubuntu, sftp, freebsd, jsch

I am using JSch to upload files to 2 servers (server A having Ubuntu, server B having FreeBSD).
The issue is on the server B (FreeBSD).  It threw the exception:
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel

Here are the last pieces of the log on each server.

For server A (Ubuntu, having no issue):

```
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
INFO: Next authentication method: password
INFO: Authentication succeeded (password).
```

For server B:

```
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Disconnecting from serverb.domainname.com port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
```

I replaced my real host with serverb.domainname.com.

What could be the issue on the server B?

I tried to set the sshd_config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config), but no luck

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

Comment: aled, thanks for your comments.  I tried that, but still got the same error.

Comment: I found a solution for this.  Changing the PasswordAuthentication to yes in the sshd_config file.  Hope this helps someone else.